# Getting Compile time error while implementing MessageCreator in ActiveMq

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, producer-consumer

I am trying to get into ActiveMq and following the tutorial on the below link:

[Spring-ActiveMq Example](https://www.journaldev.com/12743/spring-activemq-example)

While creating ActiveMQMessageProducer class i am getting compile time error for the following line:

```
textMessage.setIntProperty(MSG_COUNT, messageCount);
```

Error is

> "Cannot refer to the non-final local variable messageCount defined in
>   an enclosing scope"

What i am not getting is that how it's working according to tutorial.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in this tutorial because the method of the inner anonymous class cannot refer to a non-final variable. Here's a fixed version:

```
   public void generateMessages() throws JMSException 
{
    for (int messageCount = 0; messageCount < 10; messageCount++) 
    {
        final String text = "TP Message " + messageCount;
        final int count = messageCount; // copy the value into a final
        jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() 
        {
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException
            {
                TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(text);
                textMessage.setIntProperty(MSG_COUNT, count); // use it             
                return textMessage;
            }
        });
    }
}
```